# Sumifs 2 sets of multiple criteria

Tags: arrays, excel, sumifs, multiple-conditions

I had made some researches here before posting. I might missed something so please be nice.

Anyway, I am trying to derive the sum by having 2 sets of multiple conditions into 2 criterias.

For example,

I need the sum of dogs, fish and cats by owners Alpha and Beta.

My formula is

```
=Sum(Sumifs(Numberofpets,pet,{"dog","fish","cat"},Owner,{"Alpha","Beta"}))
```

Only the Dog has a sum. Is it possible to have 2 sets of array in sumifs?

The best alternative that I have is below.

```
=Sum(Sumifs(Numberofpets,pet,{"dog","fish","cat"},Owner,"Alpha")+Sumifs(Numberofpets,pet,{"dog","fish","cat"},Owner,"Beta"))
```

The arrays for the owners might expand in the future.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you need a number for each combination of owner and animal or a single sum over all combinations??

Comment: You'll need to transpose one of the arrays. The simplest way here is to change all of the commas to semi-colons in one (but not both) of the arrays. Effectively this makes one a single-row array, the other a single-column array, and so instructs Excel to compute a "two-dimensional" array of returns to include all necessary combinations of your criteria.

Comment: @XOR LX - I think you should post that as an answer

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I would use a named range with the array of values as the lookup condition.

```
=sumproduct(sumifs(Numberofpets,pets,choose({1,2},dogrange,ownerrange)))
```